# Using a variable as part of a control name (to constantly check a condition)

Tags: excel, vba, variables, controls

I am using toggle buttons that change color, caption and add / subtract to a counter. Since I will have to have a few of those buttons I'd rather habe a general function instead of having to change the script for each button.

This is what I currently have:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
    ToggleButton2.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    ToggleButton2.Caption = "PASS"
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + 1

    If Range("A2").Value > "0" Then
        Range("A2").Value = Range("A2").Value - 1
    End If



Else
    ToggleButton1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ToggleButton1.Caption = "FAIL"
    Range("A2").Value = Range("A2").Value + 1

    If Range("A1").Value > "0" Then
        Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value - 1
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

What I expect is something like:

```
For i = 1 to 100
    If ToggleButton & i.Value = True Then
     ....
```

Or maybe even something like
For each togglebutton do blah

So how do I use a variable in the control name? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try adapting this

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 12
    cont = me.controls("chkCheckBox" & i)
    if cont.value then
        msgbox cont.name & " is TRUE"
    endif
Next
```

Comment: doesn't work cause it can't handle: `If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then`

Comment: why doesnt it? try above just change chkCheckBox to the name of you controls minus the number of course